# ssh run script in background and get its pid

Tags: bash, ssh

Hi
I need to get the pid of the script run through ssh.

```
ssh some.host './script &' #get the pid of it
```

Some code I was trying so far:

```
ssh some.host './script & ; echo $!'
```

```
nohup ssh some.host '( ./script  & ); echo $! > thePID'; ssh some.host 'cat thePID'
```

Any sugestion?

Comment: The big problem with your second approach, by the way, is that it's setting `$!` only in a subshell, but then it's trying to `echo $!` in the *parent* of that subshell after the subshell has exited.

Comment: BTW, `nohup` does absolutely nothing you can't do yourself. `ssh some.host './script </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 & echo "$!"; disown -a'` does all the *useful* things a remote `nohup` would do, without the useless/harmful things (like creating `nohup.out` -- if you want stdout/stderr logged, do it yourself with a filename you control by specifying a destination other than `/dev/null` for the redirection).

Comment: BTW, if you're trying to use this to start a remote service, the better approach is to use a proper process supervision system -- runit, daemontools, upstart, systemd, etc.; once something is defined as a service, any of those provide commands to start them, stop them, check their status, etc. that doesn't require knowing a PID.

Comment: BTW, I'm justifying this as being a complete duplicate because the `& ;` syntax error is the only thing that's actually *wrong* -- if the OP tried running the same command locally to factor out SSH and make a [mcve] of their problem, they would have arrived at the exact same question. Thus, this question only differs by virtue of being insufficiently minimal (having failed to factor out factors irrelevant to the actual problem at hand).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ssh some.host './script & echo $!'
```

Comment: Definitely correct inasfar as it goes. That said, if the program tries to write to stdout or stderr (or read from stdin, or exits when receiving SIGHUP), it may be killed after ssh exits. To avoid this, consider redirecting those to/from a file, and/or using `disown` to prevent SIGHUP from being sent when the shell exits.

Comment: @Jakuje, it **does** in fact run `./script` in the background. A single `&` is a command terminator that puts the preceding command in the background.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, it should be this -

```
./script & echo $!
```

without

```
;
```